# Problems loading static js files on Express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to run some static javascript files that I've on `/public/js` folder.

On that folder I've a script named test.js that it simply has a `console.log('test');` inside.

On mi index.html I call this file using the following route:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/test.js"></script>`

And this is my index.js file where I've the express server:

```
const path = require("path");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.use(require("body-parser").json({}));

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("server started");
});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "/index.html"));
});
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, please if someone could assist me it will be really helpful.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: this looks correct. So you are not getting the `test` logged in console? Can you also show your network tab. refresh the page and post the network tab screenshot here.

Comment: Try set the root in the option object of the sendFile() function

Comment: @AritraChakraborty it's weird because it shows as it is loaded but it never log anything on the console https://imgur.com/a/AnuQMI5

Comment: @ReynierAlbertoRiveroAlarcón sorry but how do I do that?

Comment: okay maybe your console is getting cleared for some reason? or you have a filter there? maybe instead of console you can add alert("some string")? So that the alert msg pops up

Comment: Can you show us your folder structure, please?

Comment: res.sendFile('filepath', {root: __dirname})